# How to put command with doxygen into makefile

Tags: gnu-make

I use linux and filter doxygen output as follows:

```
doxygen 2> >(grep "Arguments.h") 1> /dev/null
```

which is just to concentrate on failures within `Arguments.h`. 
Now i want to put all that in a minimal makefile for `GNU Make 4.3`

```
doc:
    doxygen 2> >(grep "Arguments.h") 1> /dev/null
```

of course later to replace `Arguments.h` by some other file. 
But this does not work: reply is

```
doxygen 2> >(grep "Arguments.h") 1> /dev/null
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `doxygen 2> >(grep "Arguments.h") 1> /dev/null'
make: *** [makefile:2: doc] Error 1
```

as far as i know make... one has to escape sth, but no idea what... 
Any specialists which can help?

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to escaping etc.  This is related to which shell is being used.

GNU make (as with all versions of make) always invokes `/bin/sh` to run recipes, and that is a POSIX standard shell (or some proximity to it).  The command you're using is definitely *not* supported by the POSIX standard, it appears to be using many features available only as enhancements in the `bash` shell.

If you want to write your recipes using `bash` features you have to tell make that it should be using `bash` as the shell, not `/bin/sh`.  You can add this to your makefile:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thank you, worked just fine.. I love bash shell.. 
I should have known because make tells me which shell is used. On the other hand... How can this be done with posix conform shell? The requirement would be to pass the error output to grep and the rest to /dev/null

Comment: It's much simpler with POSIX than using the fancy bash features :)  Just : `doxygen 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep "Arguments.h"`  Note that order matters when using redirection!  The bash features are very powerful but they aren't needed for this simple thing.